# Case when syntax issues

Tags: sql, case-when

I'm having some issues working with a CASE WHEN statement.

```
CASE WHEN location = 'location red' Then 'First' 
    Else WHEN Location = 'location green' Then 'Second'
    Else WHEN Location = 'location blue' Then 'Last'
END AS Order
```

I keep getting a syntax error and I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the error

Comment: No else before the when Jus10

Comment: Error is a syntax error on at or near "case"

Answer (score 1):

Just this

```
CASE WHEN location = 'location red' Then 'First' 
    WHEN Location = 'location green' Then 'Second'
    WHEN Location = 'location blue' Then 'Last'
END AS Order
```

Comment: Tried running this, got a syntax error on the line with the first Case.

Comment: YEah, its normal, you need a comma after LOcation, before the first case: Select location, Case... and not Select location case...

Answer (score 0):

proper coding would be for `t-sql`

```
CASE location 
     when 'location red' Then 'First' 
     WHEN 'location green' Then 'Second'
     WHEN 'location blue' Then 'Last'
     else 'Unknown'
END AS Order
```

Comment: I tried to run this
```
SELECT location 
CASE Location 
WHEN  'Pinnacle Hills' Then 'hills' 
Else 'Unknown'
END AS 'group'
FROM appointment
LIMIT 5
```
and got a syntax error on line 2 at or new "CASE"